# Tag autocompletion should give higher ranking for tags that begin with the entered string

Tags: feature-request, editor, tag-autocomplete, algorithm

I think the tag autocompletion (when creating/editing a question) should rank those tags higher that begin with the entered string.

Otherwise it can happen that a tag is not suggested although it exactly matches the beginning.

#### Example

Stack Overflow has the tag [ebook-reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebook-reader).

When entering "ebook" in the Tags field, you get these suggestions:

- fac**ebook**
- fac**ebook**-graph-api
- fac**ebook**-javascript-sdk
- fac**ebook**-like
- fac**ebook**-php-sdk
- fac**ebook**-fql

but not "**ebook**-reader".

Comment: I would agree if this was specifically related to beginning of "words".  Sometimes the word you want is the second or third word in the tag... like if you were looking for javascript related to FB, you'd still want facebook-javascript-sdk to come up high on the list.

Comment: For your specific example, I'd call this a [tag:bug].